# htaccess and img path

Tags: php, .htaccess

When i use the following htaccess all is ok with my links

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^auteur\.html$    auteur.php    [L]
RewriteRule ^references\.html$   references.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$  contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^site/actualite\.html$  /site/actualite.php [L]
RewriteRule ^site/actualiteDetail/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)\.html$  /site/actualiteDetail.php?id=$1&titre=$2    [L]
```

The only problem is with pictures when i'm on the page mysite.com/site/actualiteDetail/17/titre.html for exemple.
The path of my img is :www.mysite.com/pub/img/img.png

How to correct this ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a slash('/') in front of the path. This is a common `.htaccess` problem.

Comment: Should this slash be added in the rewriterule like that ?
RewriteRule ^/site/actualite\.html$  /site/actualite.php [L]

Comment: No in front of the `<img />` like `<img src="/yourimage.jpg" alt="" />`

Comment: Thanks, didn't work, even if i try to display the picture like that www.mysite.com/pub/img/img.png i've a web page instead and not a picture

Comment: didn't have work online unfortunately, but all the problem is with the two last lines on the htaccess,
i've my picture only if i modified my url image like that <img src="../../../yourimage.jpg" alt="" /> (when i picked up 3 directory)
is it a problem of virtual directory or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Add to  tag: `<base href="site_url"/>`
or you can add / in front of image path.